# mysql_fetch_array and Facebook API

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

Working with the Facebook PHP SDK. I have the same .php tag in two different files, in one it works but in the other it returns nothing. Any idea? I have the same `config.php` file included in both.

```
include("config.php");
include("fbconnect.php");

if (!isset($_SESSION['user']))
{
    $valor_voto = mysql_query("select voto from $mes_id where email=$email");
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($valor_voto);
    $valor = $row['voto'];

    if ($valor == 1)
    {
        echo '<img class="icon" src="/images/greencheck.png">';
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<img class="icon" src="/images/check.png">';
    }
}
else
{
    echo '<img class="icon" src="/images/check.png">';
}
```

Looks to me that `$email` is what fails because if I input the email manually it will return any of the 2 spectated values.

Thanks for the time.

`$email` comes from `fbconnect.php`:

```
if ($user)
{
    try
    {
        // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');

        //Connecting to the database. You would need to make the required changes in the common.php file
        //In the common.php file you would need to add your Hostname, username, password and database name!
        mysqlc();

        $name     = GetSQLValueString($user_profile['name'], "text");
        $email    = GetSQLValueString($user_profile['email'], "text");
        $gender   = GetSQLValueString($user_profile['gender'], "text");
        $bio      = GetSQLValueString($user_profile['bio'], "text");
        $hometown = GetSQLValueString($user_hometown['hometown'], "text");
        $query    = sprintf("SELECT * FROM newmember WHERE email = %s", $email);
        $res      = mysql_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error() . "<br/>\n$sql");

        if ( mysql_num_rows($res) == 0 )
        {
            $iquery = sprintf("INSERT INTO newmember values('',%s,%s,%s,%s,'yes',%s)", $name, $email, $gender, $bio, $hometown);
            $ires   = mysql_query($iquery) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error() . "<br/>\n$sql");

            $_SESSION['user'] = $user_profile['email'];
            $_SESSION['id'] = $user_profile['id'];

        }
        else
        {
            $row = mysql_fetch_array($res);
            $_SESSION['user'] = $row['email'];
            $_SESSION['id'] = $user_profile['id'];
        }
    }
    catch (FacebookApiException $e)
    {
        error_log($e);
        $user = NULL;
    }
}
```

Comment: please note that the `mysql_xx()` functions are considered obsolete and are being deprecated by PHP. The php manual pages for all these functions includes a big red box saying not to use them, and to switch to either the `mysqli_xx()` functions or the PDO library. I strongly recommend making this change if at all possible.

Comment: @Maerlyn i added the source for $email. Thx for the time, i'm taking in consideration the new methods suggested on the php manual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, i had the condition

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['user']))
```

but i wasn't giving the condition

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user']))
```

so i wasn't able to retrive any info.

Thanks for the time.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the email column is a string, so you need to put the value in quotes. You should also escape it to prevent SQL injection attacks from Facebook.

```
$valor_voto=mysql_query("select voto from $mes_id where email='".mysql_real_escape_string($email)."'");
```

It would be even better to use mysqli or PDO, rather than the deprecated mysql extensions, and then you can use a prepared statement rather than substution and escaping.